# Customize React Router Render Order

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm having an issue with the render order of Routes in React Router.  As I understand it, any child Routes will render after their parents, and therefore be rendered on top of their parents in the DOM.

`<Route path="/" component={Nav}>
    <IndexRoute component={IndexView} />
    <Route path="/browse" component={BrowseView} />
 </Route>`

I have this Router setup, but after I navigate from the IndexRoute to the /browse route, the browse route renders on top of my Nav Component, and I can't click anything on the Nav Component.

My question is how to force the Nav Component to always render last, or if there's a better way of architecting my app to avoid this.

Thanks!

Comment: If you have elements appearing over each other (and preventing clicking) isn't this solved via CSS with a `z-index` property on the `Nav` component?

Comment: that did the trick!  thanks @Ashley'CptLemming'Wilson

Answer (score 2):

You can try this using switch:

```
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch, browserHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

    <BrowserRouter history={browserHistory}>
          <div>
            <Route component={Nav} />
            <Switch>
              <Route path="/" component={IndexView} />
              <Route path="/browse" component={BrowseView}/>
            </Switch>
          </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
```

I recommend you see the documentation:

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Switch

or you can follow this tutorial: https://medium.com/@pshrmn/a-simple-react-router-v4-tutorial-7f23ff27adf

Answer (score 1):

How about splitting `relative` and `absolute` route like this:

```
<Router>
    <Route path="/" component={Nav}>
        <IndexRoute component={IndexView} />
    </Route>
    <Route path="/browse" component={BrowseView} />
</Router>
```